# How to measure current load of MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, performance, profiling

How to measure current load of MySQL server? I know I can measure different things like CPU usage, RAM usage, disk IO etc but is there a generic load measure for example the server is at 40% load etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with top or htop you can follow the usage in Linux realtime

Comment: top doesn't show disk usage and with databases most of the time disk usage is more important

Answer (score 19):

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

Found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.htm).

Comment: I believe the OP wants a single load measure rather that the fine grain detail provided by the status query.

Comment: This requirement was not explicitly requested.

Answer (score 8):

The notion of "40% load" is not really well-defined. Your particular application may react differently to constraints on different resources. Applications will typically be bound by one of three factors: available (physical) memory, available CPU time, and disk IO.

On Linux (or possibly other *NIX) systems, you can get a snapshot of these with `vmstat`, or `iostat` (which provides more detail on disk IO).

However, to connect these to "40% load", you need to understand your database's performance characteristics under typical load. The best way to do this is to test with typical queries under varying amounts of load, until you observe response times increasing dramatically (this will mean you've hit a bottleneck in memory, CPU, or disk). This load should be considered your critical level, which you do not want to exceed.

Answer (score 6):

*is there a generic load measure for example the server is at 40% load ?*

Yes! there is:

```
SELECT LOAD_FILE("/proc/loadavg")
```

Works on a linux machine. It displays  the system load averages for the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes.

> System load averages is the average number of processes that are either in a runnable or uninterruptable state.  A process in a runnable state is either using the CPU or waiting to use the  CPU.
>   A process in uninterruptable state is waiting for some I/O access, eg waiting for disk.  The averages are taken over the three time intervals.  Load averages are not normalized for the number of
>   CPUs in a system, so a load average of 1 means a single CPU system is loaded all the time while on a 4 CPU system it means it was idle 75% of the time.

So if you want to normalize you need to count de number of cpu's also.

you can do that too with

```
SELECT LOAD_FILE("/proc/cpuinfo")
```

see also 'man proc'

Comment: Both functions are returning a NULL value. Tried on both Ubuntu and Osx

Comment: @siniradam, make sure you allow MySQL to access this path via the variable "secure_file_priv". by default /proc is not listed hence why it returns NULL.

Answer (score 2):

On linux based systems the standard check is usually uptime, a load index is returned according to metrics described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29).

Answer (score 1):

aside from all the good answers on this page (SHOW GLOBAL STATUS, VMSTAT, TOP...) there is also a very simple to use tool written by Jeremy Zawodny, it is perfect for non-admin users. It is called "mytop". more info @ http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/

Answer (score 0):

Hi friend as per my research we have some command like

- `MYTOP`: open source program written using PERL language
- `MTOP`: also an open source program written on PERL, It works same as MYTOP but it monitors the queries which are taking longer time and kills them after specific time.

[Link for details of above command](http://www.tecmint.com/mysql-performance-monitoring/)